# C: convertir caracter en la posición i-ésima de una cadena a entero

Tags: c, string

estoy teniendo problemas para convertir un el dígito i-ésimo de una cadena a `int`.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int countDigits(int n){
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

const char *disariumNumber(int number)
{
      char charray[countDigits(number)];
      sprintf(charray, "%d", number);
      int sum = 0;
      
      int len = strlen(charray);
      for(int i=0, pot=1; i < len ; i++,pot++){
        int as=atoi(&charray[i]);
        printf("%d\n",as);
        sum += pow(as,pot);
      }
      return sum == number ? "Disarium !!" : "Not !!";
      
}
```

En la salida se observa:

> 89
>
> 9

cuando debería de ser:

> 8
>
> 9

Y esta es mi prueba unitaria:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

const char *disariumNumber(int number);

Test(Basic_Test, Disarium_Or_NOT)
{
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(89), "Disarium !!");
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(564), "Not !!");
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(1024), "Not !!");
}
Test(Basic_Test, Larger_Numbers)
{
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(64599), "Not !!");
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(136586), "Not !!");
    cr_assert_str_eq(disariumNumber(1048576), "Not !!");
}
```

### Si alguien necesita el enunciado del ejercicio es [éste](https://www.codewars.com/kata/disarium-number-special-numbers-series-number-3/train/c).

La solución en Java que hice es la siguiente:

```
public class Solution
{
    public static String disariumNumber(int number)
    {
      String charray = number+"";
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 0, pot=1 ; i<charray.length(); i++, pot++){
        sum += Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(charray.substring(i,pot)),pot);
      }
      return sum == number ? "Disarium !!" : "Not !!";
    }
}
```

Me gustaría tener una solución equivalente, pero en lenguaje C.

Answer (score 2):

Ya pude hallar una solución:

extraje la conversión a una variable

```
 char charnum=charray[i];
 int as=atoi(&charnum);
```

y me dí cuenta de que atoi esperaba la dirección de un arreglo, no un caracter, así que le pasé la dirección del caracter en ese espaciod e memoria para que no me tratara de leer el resto del arreglo de caracteres.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int countDigits(int n){
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

const char *disariumNumber(int number)
{
      char charray[countDigits(number)];
      sprintf(charray, "%d", number);
      int sum = 0;

      int len = strlen(charray);
      for(int i=0, pot=1; i < len ; i++,pot++){
        char charnum=charray[i];
        int as=atoi(&charnum);
        sum += pow(as,pot);
      }
      return sum == number ? "Disarium !!" : "Not !!";
}
```